# How To Get a PHP File To Do The Same Thing As An inc File?

Tags: php, html, xhtml, ssi

Now all of my webpages are no longer formatted correctly because it is no longer an inc file. How do I get the php webpages to read in another php file and apply the formatting?

Originally I was just using this

```
<?php
readfile("balls.inc");
?>
</head>

<body>
<!--#include virtual="balls.inc"-->
```

But of course now this no longer works since navigation is now a php file, any suggestions on how to get the same results?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In PHP You could use include or include_once or require

```
include 'your_file.php';  // include each time you use the call
```

http://php.net/manual/it/function.include.php
or

```
include_once 'your_file.php';  // include just one time you use the call
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.include-once.php
or

```
 require 'your_file.php';  // stop execution if not find
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.require.php

in your case

```
<?php
 include "navigation.php";
 ?>
```

Comment: This would still keep all of the formatting and links that came with the navigation on the inc page?

Comment: The include technique  is for include common code ... but eventually update you question and add  a  proper sample of you content ..